# Unhandled exception when opening then closing and once again opening a new form

Tags: c#, winforms, unhandled-exception, objectdisposedexception

I'm getting `ObjectDisposedException was unhandled` with message `Cannot access a disposed object.`

This happens when initialize this child form at the beginning of my class by `MyForm myForm = new MyForm();` and then adding some text to my text box of that form by `myForm.txtBox.AppendText("Text");` and then opening my new form my form by using some button with code `myForm.Show();`. Now when my job is done I can close the form. Now, when I want to display the data again I'm getting that exception.

I want to keep the content of text box in my new form, but it seems like there is a problem that I haven't disposed everything in it.

How to avoid this so I can view the new forms content any time I press button?

Comment: How are you "closing" the form?

Comment: @M.Babcock, clicking x button on top right.

Comment: The error is because the previous form was not garbage collected... are you reusing the same variable for the instance of the form, or same form instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation on [`Form.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx):

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are
>   closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form
>   at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel
>   property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event
>   handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your
>   application, your application ends.

You could capture the `Form.Closing` event on the form, cancel the event, and hide the form instead of `Close`ing it.

Comment: Took me a while but it looks nice. Hide and then reshowing is working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you're creating an instance of `MyForm` at the start of the class and re-using it every time the button is pressed.  That won't work unfortunately.  Once the form is closed it will be disposed and hence no longer valid.  It will throw the next time you try and show it.

The easiest way to work around this is to create and display the form entirely within the button click event.  Don't reuse it's instance between clicks.

```
void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (MyForm myForm = new MyForm()) {
    myForm.txtBox.AppendText("Test");
    myForm.ShowDialog(this);
  }
}
```

If there is some state you need to keep between clicks, such as the text, then store that but not the `Form` instance.

Comment: Just for my personal education, what harm is there in keeping the form instance alive (especially if it is going to just be reinitialized each time it is reshown)? It seems to me that it would be better to keep the form alive until it is absolutely no longer used (such as application exit) to avoid having to reinstantiate it. Have I been misguided?

Comment: Well, I could do this. But then I have to do more code to save my data in an array and then each time I click button send the data to the form. I'm trying to be able to view the content as it's added from parent form.

Answer (score 1):

You should capture the FormClosing event as M.Babcock said but I'd also recommend you to check the close reason, if te user requested it, you can cancel and do whatever you want:private

```
void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        // Make your form dissappear of whatever you want
    }
}
```

Otherwise you won't be able to close it in case you want to.